# Creating a modal directive, and binding click event on it in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, using-directives

I am absolutely new to angularjs, and I may have missed a lot of concepts. I am trying to create a modal directive for my application and something bugs me out, it is how to interact with that directive.

I am using yeoman, and it I generate a modal directive using:

```
yo angular:directive modal --coffee
```

So I had this code in my directives directory:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('modal', () ->
    templateUrl: 'views/partials/modal.html'
    restrict: 'E'
    link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
      console.log 'link --test'
  )
```

And now in my `modal.html` partial, I inserted an anchor tag that will handle the click and alert me something.

```
<div><a href="" ng-click="foo()">Click Me</a></div>
```

Now where do I put the `foo` function?

I tried something like this but with no luck

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('modal', () ->
    templateUrl: 'views/partials/modal.html'
    restrict: 'E'
    link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
      console.log 'link --test'
    controller: ($scope) ->
       $scope.foo = () ->
         console.log 'clicked that anchor'
  )
```

Another question, am I doing it right, I mean is it right to create a modal directive? or directives are used in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing `foo()` in the directive controller works well.  And you're on the right track. Directives are the recommended place in Angular to do DOM manipulation - so a modal dialog is a good use case for directives.

Make sure your html initializes Angular and uses the directive like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <modal></modal>
</div>
```

Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7b8dE/) using your code plus the above html (I used the template directly just for simplicity sake).

Comment: That's a relief that I am doing it right, I just found the bug, I had
`foo() = () ->`

which should be 

`foo = () ->`

Thank you for the clarification.